# Single variable calculus problem

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a differentible function on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ prove that there exist $x_1$ and $x_2$  such that $\frac{1}{f'(x_1)}+\frac{1}{f'(x_2)} =2$ Where $f'$ is derivative of $f$ . I dont know how to solve this i tried mean value thorem.

Comment: I think we need more information about $f$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You can use [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)